# Is it right to use were only with he she it?

Tags: tense, past-tense, pronouns, conjugations

I am trying to learn some basic's of English , I want to know when we always use `Was` , `Were` , we always use `were` with `he,she,it` and `was` with `you` or whatever , Am I assuming it right ?

For example :

He was to come here today
She was doing her home work

You were to go to USA

In above examples we use `were` with `He , She , It` , so I am assuming that we always use `Were` only with He she it.

Comment: Though I think you may have gotten was/were mixed up, could you give us some example sentences of how you would use them?  And "basics" does not need an apostrophe.  With an apostrophe, it means that either basic owns something or is the short form of "basic is".  Neither of which makes sense in your context.  But don't worry: even native English speakers make that mistake from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure of the construction of the verb "to be". It seems you are having difficulty distinguishing between its forms.

First, let's establish that this is the **past** of "be".

The forms are like this:

> I was
>
> You were
>
> He/she/it was
>
> We were
>
> They were

Note that in English "you" singular and plural are not distinguishable from conjugation alone.

Here are a couple of examples that are similar to the ones in your question:

> **She was** doing her homework

This example is a bit more advanced than you may need.

> Yesterday, **I was** at home all day.

This example shows a simple past conjugation. Maybe in the comments below, you can write a similar example with "you"?

Comment: Yes this is exactly I want to know that I always use was with He/She/It

Comment: We can never use , He were , she were , it were , right ?

Comment: @Wish_2_fly Sadly, that isn't true either.  But in basic usage, *was* is correct and *were* is not.

Comment: yes this is what i am saying that we can use was with he she it , but not were with he/she/it , This also what showing in answer

Comment: @JMB You were in the college last tuesday , i think its right now :)

Comment: @Wish_2_fly - in basic usage you are correct. Keep studying!

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't right. The past tense of to be is :

- I was, you were, he/she/it was - we were, you were, they were

See the conjugation of to be: http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/be.html